# I need to modify the value of a column using Epplus

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, epplus-4

I need to modify the value of a column
First I look for the column by its name, getting the index. I would like to see how I can modify the
value of that column based on its ID, or on the contrary, on its range

```
public static class EpPlusExtensionMethods
{ 
    public static int GetColumnByName(this ExcelWorksheet ws, string columnName)
    {
        if (ws == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ws));
        return ws.Cells["1:1"].First(c => c.Value.ToString() == columnName).Start.Column;
    }
}

int columnId = ws.GetColumnByName("Birthdate");
```

Comment: What do you mean `modify the value of a column`? Set all cells to the same value? Modify a specific cell? Besides, columns don't have names, they're identified by *letters*. What you check in your code are the contents of the first row. That's just a cell value, not a column name. What you retrieve is the index, not an ID

Comment: You can use `ws.Cells[rowIdx,colIdx]` to access specific cells by index and iterate over a row's or column's cells.

Comment: Ok, it's right!